# How to ensure that join table (without model) data are unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to have read and unread status on a particular post by the specific user using Rails 5. I'm having `post_users` join table in which `post_id` and `user_id` will be stored. Posts and users associated with many to many (has and belongs to many). I don't have a model for the `post_users` table. How to check the join table in the controller?

Comment: Don't use habtm if you are storing anything more than just two foreign keys in the join table. You need to create a model and use `has_many through:`. http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

Comment: Is there any way to query the  join table  without the help of  model

Comment: Not in any good way. And you need a model anyways for the validation. Just get over the "waah I don't want a model" thing that every rails noob seems stuck on.

Comment: Okay. Can i get the way of doing that.Just want to know the possible ways

Comment: You can take a look at this Rails style guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#has-many-through

Comment: Also, without relying on Rails validation, you could create `constraints` in your database, but this should be reflected by your Rails app (i.e. not allow a Post and User to be associated twice, something like `post.users.where(users: { id: current_user.id }).exists?`).